# finding the axis of rotation for given transformation matrices

Tags: transformation, rotations

Is there a method to find the axis of rotation between two rigid bodies in     $\Bbb R^3 $ that move relative to each other? The rigid bodies are represented by two homogenous transformation matrices (orientation and position) measured at two or more discrete points in time. To better illustrate it see the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOkNB.png).

Comment: Idea: Cross product of the two axes

Comment: What two axes do you mean?

Comment: I mean the axes of the two bodies. How you choose the two axes is up to you.